# Custom RS485 Protocols

Tags: c, embedded, irq, rs485

I am writing a simple multi-drop RS485 protocol for serial communications within a distributed system.  I am using an addressable model where slave devices are given a window of 20ms to respond.  The master uC polls the connected devices for updates and they respond accordingly.  I've employed checksums and take the necessary overrun precautions to ensure that connected devices will not respond to malformed messages.  This method has proved effective in approximately 99% of situations, but I lose the packet if a new device is introduced during a communication session.  Plugging in a new device "hot" will have negative effects on the signal being monitored by the slave devices, if only for an extremely short time.  I'm on the software side of engineering, but how I can mitigate this situation without trying to recreate TCP?  We use a polling model because it is fast and does the job well for our application, no need for RTOS functionality.  I have an abundance of cycles on each cpu, think in basic terms.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sending packets over the RS485 is not a reliable communication. You will have to handle the lost of packets anyway. Of course, you won't have to reinvent TCP. But you will have to detect lost packets by means of timeout monitoring and sequence numbers. In simple applications this can be done at application level, what keeps you far off from the complexity of TCP. When your polling model discards all packets with invalid checksum this might be integrated with less effort.

If you want to check for collisions, that can be caused by hot plugs or misbehaving devices there are probably some improvements. Some hardware allows to read back the own transmissing. If you find a difference between sent data and receive data, you can assume a collision and repeat the packet. This will also require a kind of sequence numbering.

Comment: Excellent suggestion, each device is capable of listening to it's own transmissions.  Hot plugs were definitely giving me a bit of grief.  The solution is simple enough, I feel a bit silly for not having thought of it myself.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I've missed something in your question, but can't you just write the master so that if a response isn't seen from a device within the allowed time, it re-polls that device?